# Amsart with 14pt possible?

Tags: fontsize, amsart

If I try `\documentclass[14pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}` I just get the default which is less than 12pt. I tried to switch to the *memoir class* but there were so many changes I had to do that I gave up on switching the class. Is there any way to get 14pt for the amsart class?

Comment: Why would you need 14pt?

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{extsizes}` in your preamble. Also, alternatively, use `\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}`

Comment: @HarishKumar It worked: please consider posting this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg Accessibility guidelines?

Comment: @egreg: the idea was to use 14pt to send the manuscript to a proof reader - after corrections, we would revert to 12pts or maybe even 11pts -- but in the end the combination of double space and 14pts was messing with lots of TikZ pictures, so I settled with 12pt.

Comment: @egreg: also I just figured out this week I badly need reading glasses 8-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `extsizes` package to get unusual font sizes:

```
\documentclass[14pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Further, the facilities of KOMA-classes can be extended to other classes too using `scrextend` package. With this:

```
\documentclass[reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```