# Slight adjustment to all document font sizes in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize

I would like to tune layout of a document by relative adjustment of all font sizes. Now the document is `\documentclass[11pt]{book}` with LuaLaTeX. What would be a working equivalent of `\documentclass[10.8pt]{book}`? (Preferrably standard LaTeX or stand-alone packages; switching class to KOMA or similar would be difficult.)

Comment: 0.05pt is a bit less than 0.02mm: do you think you can *see* a difference?

Comment: @egreg No, but that's the point, it might reduce the document from 180 to a few pages less while being visually the same. Let me change the question to 10.8 perhaps? ;)

Comment: You can use package `scrextend` with option `fontsize=10.8pt`. You need a scalable font. But AFAIK with LuaLaTeX Latin Modern is already the default (and scalable).

Comment: Related: [Amsart with 14pt possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184777/amsart-with-14pt-possible)

Comment: @Schweinebacke could you put this as answer? Thanks!

Comment: No, because if this would be an answer the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Schweinebacke now clear, before was not marked as dupe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete Answer, because I have not tried it.  This might set you in the right direction.

The problem is that the values of the LaTeX size macros (sizes and their associated baseline skips) are hard-coded in most classes (all classes?).

You'd think `\normalsize` would be the base size and the rest proportionally larger or smaller based on some fixed factor. This it not the case as seen in the files

```
./tex/latex/base/size12.clo
./tex/latex/base/size11.clo
./tex/latex/base/size10.clo
```

or in the extended sizes

```
./tex/latex/extsizes/size17.clo
./tex/latex/extsizes/size14.clo
./tex/latex/extsizes/size20.clo
./tex/latex/extsizes/size9.clo
./tex/latex/extsizes/size8.clo
```

I think you'd need to create your own `size10.8.clo` file that defines the following standard sizes.

```
\tiny                   
\scriptsize         
\footnotesize       
\small      
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge    
\Huge
```

Comment: `book` will not use `size10.8.clo` nor `book10.8.clo`, because it even does not recognize option `10.8pt`.