# Increase font size of entire document in \documentclass{exam}

Tags: fontsize, document-classes, exam

I am setting up a question paper using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
```

However, I would like to increase the font size to 15pt for the entire document.

I found out from [this tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt) question that we can use `extsizes` and use something like `extarticle` instead of `article` and increase the font size up to 20pt.

How can it be done for the `\documentclass{exam}` ?

Comment: Related: [Amsart with 14pt possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184777/amsart-with-14pt-possible)

Comment: Did you try using `extarticle`? The `exam' class is based on the `article' class.

Comment: @MikeTaylor Could you elaborate (perhaps as an answer rather than a comment) how you could use `extarticle` with `exam` class? I assumed if you used `extarticle` you wouldn't be able to use the environments in `exam`.

Comment: @beldaz I have never used `exarticle` but [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402049/39194), which you know about, provides a good example.

Comment: @MikeTaylor Yes, that answer also answers this question well now.